# Rails 4: Change an integer from the index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, integer, link-to

I am making a clone of [Joe's Goals](http://www.joesgoals.com/). I have a very rough version of this that I built with a rails scaffold. The week's table has 7 days and the name of a habit. My problem is how do I increase the number of occurrences (integer representing how often you did that habit) from the index.html.erb view, without entering the edit form. 
I looked at a couple of things on S.O. building custom methods in my controller. 
How can I make a link_to in my index table field so that it changes the integer.

Here is what my [Table](http://cl.ly/image/182k0c462s3J) looks like. The way its set up is like this:

```
class CreateWeeks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :weeks do |t|
      t.string :habit
      t.boolean :gob
      t.integer :sunday
      t.integer :monday
      t.integer :tuesday
      t.integer :wednesday
      t.integer :thursday
      t.integer :friday
      t.integer :saturday


      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see i've put a couple up/down arrows to show what I am trying to do. Right now they just link to my root path. As I said, I would like them to change the value of the integer in the selected field. I've only put the arrows on monday in this image btw.

in my controller I have:

```
def increase
  @week = Week.find(params[:id])
  @week.update_attribute("monday", monday += 1)
  @week.save
  flash[:notice] = "Habit Increased."
end
```

I am trying to increase the integer with this link:

```
<%= link_to "+ 1", :method => :increase, :monday => @increase %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AJAX? If you are not, then you should be using AJAX on rails. You can check this [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) and also may be this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xEHK13u5Kc) will help you in achieving what you need.